# Не получается построить условие

Tags: php, if

Задание:Составьте массив дней недели. С помощью цикла foreach выведите все дни недели, субботу и воскресенье жирным, а текущий день выведите курсивом (если это суббота или воскресенье то отобразить и жирным и курсивом). Текущий день должен храниться в переменной $day.

```
<?php 
$day='вс';
$arr=['пн', 'вт', 'ср', 'чт', 'пт', 'сб', 'вс'];

foreach ($arr as $value) {
    if ($value=='сб' or $value=='вс' and $value==$day) {
            echo '<i><b> '.$value.'</b></i>'.' ';
    } 
    else {
        if ($value=='сб' or $value=='вс') {
            echo '<b>'.$value.'</b>'.' ';
        }
        else {
        if ($value==$day) {
        echo '<i>'.$value.'</i>';
        } 
            else {
            echo ' '.$value.' ';
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: ваша задача не требует вложенных условий. нужны два последовательных условия и все.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($arr as $value) {
    $r = $value;

    if ($value=='сб' or $value=='вс') {
        $r = "<i>{$r}</i>";
    }

    if ($value == $day) {
        $r = "<b>{$r}</b>";
    }

    $r .= '  ';

    echo $r;
}
```

Comment: в данном решении если будет сб или вс они будут только курсивом, а жирности не будет.

Comment: Поменяйте местами <i></i> и <b></b>